# Laravel - Prevent extra characters slug parameters

Tags: php, laravel, url, routes, slug

I have multiple routes with route model binding that direct users from **Shop** > **Category** > **Product**. The route links are working fine.

But if a user adds a garbage value to the URL, Laravel does not throw 404 error. How can force 404 error if a user adds any extra character to URL?

**Route**

```
Route::get('/{shop_url}/{category_url}/{product_url}/buy', 'Controller@buy')->name('buy')->where(['shop_url', 'category_url', 'product_url' => '[\w\d\-]+(.*)']);

Route::get('/{shop_url}/{category_url}', 'Controller@view')->name('view')->where(['shop_url','category_url' => '[\w\d\-]+(.*)']);

Route::get('/{shop_url}', 'Controller@shop')->name('shop')->where('shop_url', '[\w\d\-]+(.*)');
```

**Controller**

```
public function shop($shop_url)
{
  $shop = Shop::where('shop_url', $shop_url)->firstorfail();
  return view ('shop', compact('shop'));
}

public function view($shop_url, $category_url)
{
  $shop = Shop::where('shop_url', $shop_url)->firstorfail();
  $category= Category::firstorfail();

  return view ('shop', compact('shop', 'category'));
}

public function buy($shop_url, $category_url, $product_url)

{
  $shop = Shop::where('shop_url', $shop_url)->firstorfail();
  $category= Category::where('category_url', $category_url)->firstorfail();
  $product = Product::firstorfail();

  return view ('shop', compact('shop', 'category', 'product'));
}
```

Here `domain.com/shop-ca/clothing` works and if user types `domain.com/shop-ca/clothes`, it also displays the same page. Here I want it to display 404. How would I do that?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should check your slug, in your code I see these lines:

```
$category= Category::firstorfail();// it will get the first route in the database, not the needed category
```

So, first, try to do this:

```
public function view($shop_url, $category_url)
{
   $shop = Shop::where('shop_url', $shop_url)->firstOrfail();
   $category= Category::where('category_url', $category_url)->firstOrfail();// I actually don't know the name of your slug field, but if the category is wrong, laravel will return 404 page.

   return view ('shop', compact('shop', 'category'));
}
```

Comment: For ``View`` method it worked. But for ``buy`` method? I generate ``product-url`` from product name with ``str_slug($product-name)``? There is no column for ``product_url`` in table.

Comment: Well, do this: `$product = Product::where('product-url', $product_url)->firstOrfail();`

Comment: This works for ``domain.com/shop/products`` but not for ``domain.com/shop/product/buy`` or ``domain.com/shop/products-1/buy``

Answer (score 0):

You have check `$product_url` in your `buy` function and through 404 error manually.